# $match in $addFields MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, match

I am in middle of extracting MongoDb collection as I wanted, and stuck here. This is the result I get after processing. I need this to process further to project corresponding stage_name from journal array, matching `stage_id`.

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "article_journal" : "jnl_2",
        "stage_id" : "jnl_2_wf_2",
        "stage_code" : "review"
    },
    "article_count" : 1.0,
    "journal_title" : "Test Journal",
    "journal" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cd10b325586e9122761f675"),
            "jnl_code" : "jnl_2",
            "jnl_title" : "Test Journal",
            "jnl_workflow" : [ 
                {
                    "wf_stages" : [ 
                        {
                            "wf_stage_id" : "jnl_2_wf_1",
                            "wf_stage_code" : "submit",
                            "wf_stage_name" : "Submit",
                        }, 
                        {
                            "wf_stage_id" : "jnl_2_wf_2",
                            "wf_stage_code" : "review",
                            "wf_stage_name" : "Review",
                        }, 
                        {
                            "wf_stage_id" : "jnl_2_wf_3",
                            "wf_stage_code" : "publish",
                            "wf_stage_name" : "Publish",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

the result should look like

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "article_journal" : "jnl_2",
        "stage_id" : "jnl_2_wf_2",
        "stage_code" : "review"
    },
    "article_count" : 1.0,
    "journal_title" : "Test Journal",
    "stage_name" : "Review"
}
```

I tried:

```
{'$addFields':{'stage_name':{
    '$match':{'stage_name':'$journal.[0].jnl_workflow[0].wf_stages.$[i].wf_stage_name'}
    },
    arrayFilters:[{'i.wf_staeg_id':'$_id.stage_id'}]
}}
```

but is thorows an error:

```
"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$match'",
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: User $cond instead of $match

Comment: Take a look at this https://mongoplayground.net/p/r5zmj4RYNGo  go and check weather this works for you

Comment: $cond will not work here. since the stage_id is completely dynamic so we cannot hard code stage_id, as you suggeest @GaurangDhorda

Comment: @rbvishnu check out this https://mongoplayground.net/p/ANu6J0Yl0IG $map is what works for you ..

Comment: the result seems same, projecting stage_code. I need to get stage_name @GaurangDhorda